# How do you hook up Azure notification Hub to a Ionic React app?

Tags: reactjs, azure, android-notifications, azure-notificationhub, ionic-react

I have a Azure Notification hub that's hooked up to a FCM instance. I am able to send notifications to my app using the Firebase console. There is a component which registers my device and changes to the build.gradle files which link the device and FCM (following this guide https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-push-notification-in-ionic-react-capacitor/111/).
But I want to use an Azure notification hub instead.

What needs to be added to the gradle.build/google-services.json/any other files for the app to be linked with Azure?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a bit of digging i've solved this issue. I'll list the steps below -

- Run `npm i` in your ionic-react app and then `npx cap add android` then `npx cap open android`.
- Register on Firebase following [this guide.](https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-push-notification-in-ionic-react-capacitor/111/) Download the google-services.json file. Add this file to the android/app/ folder. Then add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the bottom of the build.gradle in the android/app/ folder.
- Go back to the firebase console > project overview > project settings > cloud messaging and copy the server key.
- Paste the server key into your Azure notification hub under the Google (GCM/FCM) tab and save. Azure and Firebase are now linked.
- Plug in a device and run your app from Android studio.
- Register for push notifications in your app (code for this found on link above).
- App is now able to receive notifications.

I don't think this is a fully 'correct' answer as you cannot send manual test notifications from Azure to Android, but it satisfies my requirements and is hopefully helpful to someone else. 
Thanks.